# Can std::invalid_argument be feeded with a what_arg of nulllptr?

Tags: c++

Can `std::invalid_argument` be fed with a `what_arg` of `nullptr` when I call its constructor ? Or do I have to pass at least an empty string ?

Comment: Check out cppreference.com.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: There's no information on that.

Comment: Why not just pass an empty string literal instead? I imagine most implementations just pass `const char*` to a `std::string` like object which will have undefined behaviour with a null pointer

Comment: @AlanBirtles: The what()-string is allocated on the heap (reference counted so that the copy-constructor of invalid_argument doesn't throw an exception) and I want to prevent this allocation.

Comment: You can't avoid it, the rest of the class would be much more complex if it had to handle the message being null, why do you want to avoid it? Throwing and catching the exception is likely much more expensive than allocating the string (which typically isn't heap allocated to avoid failing to allocate exception messages when the system is out of memory)

Comment: It is practically impossible to implement the requirements of `std::exception` (copy constructor being `noexcept`) without heap allocation. If the heap allocation is a no-go for you, you cannot use `std::invalid_argument`.

Comment: I don't want to have pros and cons about heap allocation but just some reliable information on if I can pass a nullptr as a what_arg.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the answer myself in the C++20 draft under 19.2.4: "invalid_argument(const char* what_arg);" => "Postconditions: strcmp(what(), what_arg) == 0.". And strcmp doesn't honor nullptr-string in a way that it ignores it.